# Leading trailing space removal

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading content from a text file which contains below contents

```xml
    <ID> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form>
```

My requirement is whatever I have inside ID, Sub_tab tags I want to take off the trailing and leading spaces from the content inside those tags, but the content inside the form tag should be untouched. My output should come as:

```xml
    <iD>test data</Id> <Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab> <form> form data </form>
```

Tried using many patterns, but none of them worked

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/>[ \t]+</");
string newContent = regex.Replace(fileContent, "><");
```

Comment: Obligatory "If this is XML use an XML parser" comment.

Comment: Regex is definitely the wrong tool. Use an XML parser and XPath. Here, `//id/text()|//sub_tab/text()`

Comment: This looks like an XML string. Parsing XML with regex is *not* easy. Use an XML parser instead . BTW XML is case sensitive. You can't have `<ID>` and `</Id>` in an XML string

Comment: `s = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+(</(?:ID|Sub_Tab)>)", "$1"), @"(<(?:ID|Sub_Tab)>)\s+", "$1")`. Or even `Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+(</(?:ID|Sub_Tab)>)|(<(?:ID|Sub_Tab)>)\s+", "$1$2")`

Comment: @UmeshKumar - XML is also a text file with tags. Could you post a sample file if it's not too long. If it follows the XML format, a parser is definitely what you want.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. Do you have a regex which identifies if there is  a leading trailing spaces between any tags for example <ID> test data </Id>

Comment: Why _specifically_ do you want to use a regex to parse XML?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of feels like overkill. Maybe because it's an overkill?
Anyway, you might be able to do this easily using regex. But at this time, I'm not familiar with regex.
So, this is my solution to your problem. Here it comes.

```cs
string input = "<ID> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form>";

string find = "ƸƷ";
// ƸƷ - If you have these two characters in your input string, then this won't work.
// These characters (ƸƷ) can be replaced with any unique string. However, this function 
// to work, that string should not be contained in the input string 
// or it will mess the replace function. This can be done without using 
// these characters. But it might require more coding. So, I'm going with this.
string str = input;

IList < string > strList = new List < string > ();

// Remove all content inside the form tags
while (true) {
 if ((str.Contains("<form>")) && (str.Contains("</form>"))) {
  int start = str.IndexOf("<form>");
  int end = str.IndexOf("</form>");

  string result = str.Substring(start, end - start + 7); // 7 = "</form>".Length             
  str = str.Replace(result, find);
  strList.Add(result);
 } else {
  break;
 }
}

// Manipulate the data
str = str.Replace(" <", "<").Replace("> ", ">");

// Add the contents inside the form tags
foreach(string val in strList) {
 int place = str.IndexOf(find);
 str = str.Remove(place, find.Length).Insert(place, val);
}

Console.WriteLine("Input String: " + input);
Console.WriteLine("Output String: " + str);
```

Example 01

```html
<ID> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form> 
<ID>test data</Id><Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab><form> form data </form>
```

Example 02

```html
<ID> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data <div> data </div> </form> <br>
<ID>test data</Id><Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab><form> form data <div> data </div> </form><br>
```

Example 03

```html
<ID> test data </Id> <form> <span> date </span> </form> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form>
<ID>test data</Id><form> <span> date </span> </form><Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab><form> form data </form>
```

Online Demo: https://rextester.com/FZU31740